# ¿Cómo puedo detectar cuánto espacio queda en la pantalla de un celular para un input "select" con varias opciones?

Tags: html5, responsive

tengo un input type ="select" ( o "combobox") personalizado que contiene muchas opciones, cuando pongo este elemento al final de la pantalla la lista se corta por el límite de la misma en dispositivos móviles. Estaba pensando en una función responsive que detecte cuando ya no haya espacio para desplegar la lista de opciones por debajo, que la despliegue arriba con un scroll, si alguien tuviera documentación o alguna forma de detectar esta situación me sería muy útil, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score -1):

Buenas tardes amigo puedes utilizar la libreria de Select2 que a demas de ser responsive, tiene integrado mejor diseño de select y tiene tambien select-multiple:

[Url Select2](https://select2.org/)

Complemento: Cuenta con CDN

Donde lo debes llamar en tu master o plantilla inicial en caso de tener una o sino en el mismo html.

```
Etiquetas LINK CDN:
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Seguido donde quieras agregar tu Select:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="name_select"> 
   <option select disabled>Seleccionar</option>
   <option value="1">Mexico</option>
   <option value="2">Peru</option>
   <option value="3">Chile</option>
</select>
```